# Search from database java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, hsqldb, dao

im trying to create a servlet where i can add , delete and search customers, now i got stuck with search method, im not sure why my method doesnt work but heres the code i´ve created so far. I am using DAO pattern with a following method for filtering customers by name and surname:

```
public List<Customers> filterCustomer(String name)
{
    List<Customers> customers = new ArrayList<Customers>();

    try{
        st = getConnection().createStatement();     
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from customer where first_name  like '%" + name + "%'"
                + "and surname like '%" + name+ "%'");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Customers customer = new Customers();
            customer.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            customer.setFirst_name(rs.getString(2));
            customer.setSurname(rs.getString(3));
            customer.setCode(rs.getString(4));

            customers.add(customer);


        }
```

In servlet first i create List of customers to print them out, but if the searchString parameter is not null then i want to create new list of these customers which match the searchString. Heres the servlet part i`ve created :

```
out.print("<form method=\"get\" action =\"" + request.getContextPath() +"/Search\" >"
    + "<input id='searchStringBox' name='searchString'/>"
    + "<input type='submit' value='Filtreeri'>");
CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
    List<Customers> customers;
    customers = dao.getAllCustomers();
    String name = request.getParameter("searchString"); 
    if(name != null) 

    customers = dao.filterCustomer(name); 

    out.println("<table id='listTable' class='listTable>'" +
    "<thead><tr><th scope='col'>Nimi</th><th scope='col'>Perekonnanimi</th>"
    +"<th scope='col'>Kood</th><th scope='col'></th></tr></thead>");

    for(Customers customer : customers)
    {
        String value3 = String.valueOf(customer.getId());
        request.setAttribute("value3",value3);
        customer.getId();
        out.println(        
    "<tbody><tr> "      
    + "<td>"+ customer.getFirst_name()+" "+"</td>"
    + "<td>"+ customer.getSurname()+" "+"</td>"
    + "<td>"+ customer.getCode()+" " +"</td>"
    + " "+"<td><a href='"+request.getContextPath()+"/Search?id="+value3+"'>Delete</a></td></tr>"                    
     );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for customers who have a common string between the name and surname. For example, if you search for "Moses", you'll find only people like:

```
Moses Moses
Moses Mosesson
Moses O'Moses
```

...etc. It will **not** find "Moses Malone" or "Jenny Moses".

The reason for this is that your condition is AND instead of OR. So it checks that both the name and the surname are like '%Moses%' together.

Change the query to:

```
"SELECT * from customer where first_name  like '%" + name + "%'"
            + "OR surname like '%" + name+ "%'"
```

After you make sure this works, please read about [SQL Injection and how to prevent it](http://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection). Never use parameters that came from the outside world (the person or hacker who uses your servlet) without checking them for potential SQL Injection.

Comment: THank you, but can you explain "parameters that came outside world".

Comment: I mean, values that originate from end users. You cannot control what they will send your server. The values come from outside of your own machine, from the Internet, and so you should suspect them.